# подскажите нужное решение в хранимой процедуре

Tags: sql, sql-server

Коллеги, добрый день.
Попался в тесте вопрос: нужно создать хранимую процедуру, которая будет использоваться сотнями пользователей одновременно. Нужно хранить строки, которые позже будут обработаны моей хранимкой. решение должно соответствовать следующим требованиям:

- быть индексируемым
- содержать актуальную статистику
- быть масштабируемым от 10 до 100000 строк

Решение должно предотвращать доступ пользователей к данным друг друга.

---

Мне на ум приходит использование временной таблицы в хранимой процедуре , но это неверный ответ. Подскажите, куда правильно мыслить? 
Смущает предложение "предотвращать доступ пользователей к данным друг друга"

Comment: А как вы идентифицируете пользователей ? Надеюсь у них есть некие вменяемые id. Тогда делается обычная таблица и в ней колонка user_id. Процедура при всех действиях с таблицей указывает условия на этот id.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит "хранить строки, которые позже будут обработаны моей хранимкой". Что вообще должна выполнять хранимка? То есть строки нужно сохранить внутри и потом обработать или где-то сохранить, а потом вызвать процедуру (для каждой сохраненной строки отдельно? или для всего набора?)?

Answer (score 0):

Прочитав полезную  [статью](http://sqlcom.ru/helpful-and-interesting/compare-temp-table-vs-table-variable-vs-cte/), я пришел к выводу, что нет такого решения, потому что условиям индексирования, актуальной статистики, и количеством строк от 10 до 100000 удовлетворяет временная таблица (#TABLE), но она не удовлетворяет условию закрытия параллельного доступа пользователями. Этому условию удовлетворяют табличная переменная (Table Variable) или же временное табличное выражение (CTE), но они частично  удовлетворяют первым трем условиям (индексированию, кол-ву строк от 10 до 100000, актуальной статистике)

Comment: Локальные временные таблицы (с одним #) ограничены соединением, данные пользователей будут изолированы